# If statements doesn't work in tkinter. Fucntion doesn't do anything. No errors

Tags: python, function, if-statement, tkinter

I'm building an app that shows a list of movies in certain genre, when user's mood is chosen. The program works not as intended. The button "Show list" doesn't work. I'm not sure where is the problem, whether in "if statements" or function. The program works. The dropdown menu does as well. However, the program doesn't execute the function.

```
import json
import tkinter as tk
from tokenize import Name
from unicodedata import name
from xml.dom.minicompat import StringTypes
import pandas as pd
import requests
import class_object

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title("Movie chooser based on mood")


data = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US")
data = json.loads(data.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


#genres


mood_options = ['Happy',]
clicked = tk.StringVar()
clicked.set("What's your mood?")
genre = tk.StringVar()
options = [class_object.Happy.name,class_object.Emotional.name,class_object.Scared.name,class_object.Mysterious.name,class_object.Fantasy.name,class_object.Curious.name,class_object.White_noise.name]

drop = tk.OptionMenu(root, clicked,*options).pack()

def find_movie():
    if options == class_object.Happy.name:
        movie_list = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Comedy%2CAdventure%2CAnimation%2CFamily&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_list = json.loads(movie_list.text)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)
        for i in range(0,20):
            i
            genre.set(['results'][i]['original_title'])


    if options == class_object.Emotional.name:
        movie_list = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Drama%2CRomance&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_list = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)

        for i in range(0,20):
            i
            My_lebel = tk.Label(root, text = df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()

    if options == class_object.Scared.name:
        movie_list = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Horror%2C%20Thriller&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_list = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)

        for i in range(0,20):
            i
            My_lebel = tk.Label(root, text = df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()

    if options == class_object.Mysterious.name:
        movie_list = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Mystery&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_lsit = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)

        for i in range(0,20):
            i
            My_lebel = tk.Label(root, text = df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()

    if options == class_object.Fantasy.name:
        movie_list = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Fantasy%2CFiction&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_list = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)
        for i in range(0,20):
            i
            genre.set(df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()
    if options == class_object.Curious.name:
        movie_list = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Documentary&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_list = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)
        for i in range(0,20):
            i
            My_lebel = tk.Label(root, text = df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()
    if options == class_object.White_noise.name:
        movie_list = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=TV%20movie&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_lsit = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)
        for i in range(0,20):
            i
            My_lebel = tk.Label(root, text = df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text ='Show the list', command = find_movie).pack()
my_lable = tk.Label(root, textvariable=genre).pack()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `options` is a list. `class_object.Happy.name` is an element of the same list. How do expect `options == class_object.Happy.name` ever to be true? When will the full list be exactly the same as one of its elements?

Comment: I think you want `x in y` instead of `y == x`, though you probably want to the user to *select* a value from the menu compare *that* to each object, rather than checking/confirming that menu options are, indeed, in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run your script, as `class_objects` is not provided. However, you need to change your if statements. `if options == class_object.Happy.name:`, should be `if genre.get() in class_object.Happy.name:`. You are comparing a list to an object which will never be True as @Mattias stated, And it is not what you want. Instead, you want to be comparing the genre variable.
Ex.

```py
import json
import tkinter as tk
from tokenize import Name
from unicodedata import name
from xml.dom.minicompat import StringTypes
import pandas as pd
import requests
import class_object

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title("Movie chooser based on mood")

data = requests.get(
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US")
data = json.loads(data.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# genres


mood_options = ['Happy', ]
clicked = tk.StringVar()
clicked.set("What's your mood?")
genre = tk.StringVar()
options = [class_object.Happy.name, class_object.Emotional.name, class_object.Scared.name, class_object.Mysterious.name,
           class_object.Fantasy.name, class_object.Curious.name, class_object.White_noise.name]

drop = tk.OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options).pack()


def find_movie():
    moodtext = clicked.get()
    if moodtext == class_object.Happy.name:
        movie_list = requests.get(
            "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Comedy%2CAdventure%2CAnimation%2CFamily&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_list = json.loads(movie_list.text)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)
        for i in range(0, 20):
            
            genre.set(['results'][i]['original_title'])

    if moodtext == class_object.Emotional.name:
        movie_list = requests.get(
            "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Drama%2CRomance&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_list = json.loads(movie_list.text)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)

        for i in range(0, 20):
            
            My_lebel = tk.Label(root, text=df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()

    if moodtext == class_object.Scared.name:
        movie_list = requests.get(
            "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Horror%2C%20Thriller&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_list = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)

        for i in range(0, 20):
            
            My_lebel = tk.Label(root, text=df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()

    if moodtext == class_object.Mysterious.name:
        movie_list = requests.get(
            "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Mystery&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_lsit = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)

        for i in range(0, 20):
            
            My_lebel = tk.Label(root, text=df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()

    if moodtext == class_object.Fantasy.name:
        movie_list = requests.get(
            "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Fantasy%2CFiction&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_list = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)
        for i in range(0, 20):
            
            genre.set(df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()
    if moodtext == class_object.Curious.name:
        movie_list = requests.get(
            "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=Documentary&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_list = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)
        for i in range(0, 20):
            
            My_lebel = tk.Label(root, text=df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()
    if moodtext == class_object.White_noise.name:
        movie_list = requests.get(
            "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=25edbcd94c9f3ff7a7af1c08760aa632&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_count.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=TV%20movie&with_watch_monetization_types=free")
        movie_lsit = json.loads(movie_list)
        df_movie = pd.DataFrame(movie_list)
        for i in range(0, 20):

            My_lebel = tk.Label(root, text=df_movie['results'][i]['original_title'])
            My_lebel.pack()


button = tk.Button(root, text='Show the list', command=find_movie).pack()
my_lable = tk.Label(root, textvariable=genre).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It should be using `clicked` instead of `genre`.  Also it is better to call `clicked.get()` once instead of calling it in every if statement.

Comment: Yes, I will make some edits.